# Hair "running away" from one single point in space (all hair directed away from this point)

Tags: particles, hair

I have a problem: I have created a sphere and added a particle system to it (hair), but for some reason all the other hair that I created afterwards are pointing away from that original hair. I didn't add a force field to anything. It seems they are linked somehow and the original hair acts as a force field source.

Here is the blend file which is causing the problem:

[image]

I can also provide a screenshot of the problem but it is self explanatory.

Comment: Need a request to watch your video, so I sent one. However, this is not the ideal way to share your issues. You can visit here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - and upload your .blend file for us to look at, or post a screenshot of your problem. This will allow the community to help you better.